# reference for Levelt-Turritin

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, connections

Can anybody recommend a good reference to learn the Levelt-Turritin decomposition theorem of formal connections? An intuitive description of what it says would also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For a new approach and intuitive explanation see [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.03608.pdf). In the older literature, Levelt's Original [paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02386195#page-1) is the best reference I have found! In particular, it is more understandable than many references that come after. The statement is very simple: every differential operator over the field $\overline{\mathbb{C}((t))}$ has a Jordan canonical form.